# qBittorrent - List directories/folders first under torrent content

Tags: qbittorrent

I would like to list the directories under torrent contents first. Is this possible? I have checked the settings to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can not see the file without putting the torrent in the queue. But you can use an existing library for write a parser for torrent file, or you can also write your own library, using the specifications of the torrent explained [here](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification).